# Angular 2: How to pass the router in md-list-item?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am populating a list of object using `md-nav-list`. When user clicks on a `md-list-item`, I want to navigate to candidate-detail router and pass the `candidate.id` with it.

Not sure how to call the router on `md-list-item`.

```
  <md-nav-list *ngFor="let candidate of candidates">
    <md-list-item class="candidate-row">
      <div class="column2">
        <span class="name">{{candidate.name}},</span>
      </div>
    </md-list-item>
  </md-nav-list>
```

the router for candidate detail is 
 `{path: 'candidate/:id', component: CandidateDetailsComponent}`

Rest of the code can be found here 
https://github.com/himanshuy/hiringplus-ui/tree/page2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass id with routerLink as shown below :

```
<md-list-item class="candidate-row" [routerLink]="['candidate',{id:candidate.id}]">
        ...
</md-list-item>
```

the router for candidate detail is

```
 {path: 'candidate/:id', component: CandidateDetailsComponent}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `routerLink` directive to form URL

```
<a class="name" [routerLink]="['candidate', candidate.id]">
   {{candidate.name}},
</a>
```

Comment: the whole `<md-list-item>` is a link. something needs to be specified at the row level.

Comment: Then apply it on `md-list-item` element

Answer (score 0):

You can add the [routerLink](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html) directive to the md-list-item components (or any other component):

```
<md-list-item class="candidate-row" [routerLink]="['candidate', candidate.id]">
    ...
</md-list-item>
```